# how to get correct row data with certain restrict in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I want to extract the correct row based on certain condition.

The dataframe contains a column entry with the entry signals. 
A valid entry only when there is no order in market. Therefore, only the first signal is valid in two consecutive signals 
A valid exit is 5 bars later after entry.

Here is my code and dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'entry':[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
df['exit'] = df['entry'].shift(5)

df['state'] = np.select([df['entry'] == 1, df['exit'] == 1], [1, 0], default=np.nan)
df['state'].ffill(inplace=True)
df['state'].fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
df['change'] = df['state'].diff()
print(df)


entrysig = df[df['change'].eq(1)]
exitsig = df[df['change'].eq(-1)]

tradelist = pd.DataFrame({'entry': entrysig.index, 'exit': exitsig.index})

tradelist['wantedexit'] = [6, 12]

print(tradelist)
```

The output is like :

```
    entry  exit  state  change
0       0   NaN    0.0     NaN
1       1   NaN    1.0     1.0
2       0   NaN    1.0     0.0
3       1   NaN    1.0     0.0
4       0   NaN    1.0     0.0
5       0   0.0    1.0     0.0
6       0   1.0    0.0    -1.0
7       1   0.0    1.0     1.0
8       0   1.0    0.0    -1.0
9       0   0.0    0.0     0.0
10      0   0.0    0.0     0.0
11      0   0.0    0.0     0.0
12      0   1.0    0.0     0.0
13      0   0.0    0.0     0.0
   entry  exit  wantedexit
0      1     6          6
1      7     8         12
```

In this example, the first trade entered at bar 1 exit at 6 is correct, it enters at bar 1 and exit after 5 bars which is 6.

The entry on bar 3 is ignored because there is currently an order in market which entered at bar 1.

The second trade entered at bar 7 and exit bar 8 is not correct, because the trade only last for 1 bar while my condition is to exit after 5 bars.

The exit at bar 8 is there because there is an invalid signal at bar 3.

The 'wantedexit' column should be the correct exit bar index.

Comment: unclear to me ....

Comment: I have edited the statement and hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: Then isn't `wantedexit` is just `entry+5`?